Problem With Groovy Script in Active Choice Parameter in Freestyle Job Jenkins
I want to make active choice parameter with list of all the projects that contains 'release' in it's name as it option, but it always fails.
The groovy script looked like this:
import jenkins.* 
def projectNames = [] 

Jenkins.instance.items.findAll.each { 
  item -> if (item.name.contains("release")) { 
    projectNames.add(item.name)
  }
 } 

return projectNames.join('\n')

Is there any answer as to why it keeps failing?


import needs more information
findAll is a method call and requires brackets. And it's unnecessary
the plugin expects a list back, not a new line separated string

import jenkins.model.*
def projectNames = []
Jenkins.instance.items.each { item ->
  if (item.name.contains("release")) {
    projectNames.add(item.name)
  }
}
return projectNames

Or, if you like oneliners
return jenkins.model.Jenkins.get().items.findAll{it.name.contains("release")}.name


This works for me:
import jenkins.* 
def projectNames = []
Jenkins.instance.items.each { item -> 
  if (item.name.contains("release")) { 
    projectNames.add(item.name)
  } 
} 
return projectNames.join('\n')

It seems that there is no findAll method on the list Jenkins.instance.items.
